# Does Grails 4 supports both multi-datasource and multi-tenant?

Tags: java, grails

I have to implement the both techniques in grails 4:

1. Multi datasource
2. Multi tenant

Is it possible? if yes than how?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Grails 4 **does support** both, Multi-Datasources and Multi-Tenancy.

More specifically, Grails supports:

- **Multiple Datasources** since Grails **2.x**
- **Multiple Tenancy** since Grails **3.2**

### Multi-Datasources

From the official documentation, here is **how to do** Multi-Datasources:

- In [Grails 2](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.6/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources)
- In [Grails 3](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.11/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources)
- In [Grails 4](http://docs.grails.org/4.0.12/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources)

### Multi-Tenancy

Multi-Tenancy is supported by GORM (the Grails' Object Relational Mapping) since GORM 6.0, introduced with Grails 3.2

From the official documentation, here is **how to do** Multi-Tenancy:

- Since [Grails 3.2 / GORM 6.0](https://gorm.grails.org/6.0.0/hibernate/manual/#multiTenancy)
- Since [Grails 3.3 / GORM 6.1](https://gorm.grails.org/6.1.0/hibernate/manual/#multiTenancy)
- Since [Grails 4.0 / GORM 7.0](https://gorm.grails.org/7.0.0/hibernate/manual/#multiTenancy)

I have succesfully implemented Multi-Tenancy on two different Grails Projects. One of them was on a previously working application, and the adaptation was pretty straightforward using the DISCRIMINATOR approach.

Here a couple of tutorials on Multi-Tenancy with Grails, one using the DATABASE approach, and the other using the DISCRIMINATOR approach:

- [Database per Tenant Multi-Tenancy](https://guides.grails.org/database-per-tenant/guide/index.html)
- [Single Database Multi-Tenancy - Discriminator Column](https://guides.grails.org/discriminator-per-tenant/guide/index.html)